# In R, how can I merge or fill rows with NA "up" to make data complete

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lapply, missing-data

I have data that very unclear, but I have been tidying it up. I am now in a situation where every two rows is the complete data and should be one row, but each row contains NAs and no key.

an example:

```
df <- data.frame(Name=c("Steve",NA,"Jim",NA,"Patty",NA),Age=c(NA,26,NA,41,NA,37),Gender=c(NA,"M",NA,"M",NA,"F"))
```

So we see something like:

|Name...Age...Gender
|

|Steve....NA...... NA

|NA........ 26........ M

But what I need is

Steve 26 M

So the data is there, but I am not sure how to fill it down...I could possible fill down the Name column where is NA. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  fill(Name) %>%
   group_by(Name) %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(Age)) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Name    Age Gender
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
1 Steve    26 M     
2 Jim      41 M     
3 Patty    37 F
```